# Why does the function work except @click?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3

I using Vue3 and firestore

Here's my problem.

```
<textarea class="form-control v-model="form.comment" @keypress.enter="saveComment" required></textarea>
<button @click="saveComment">save</button>
```

@keypress.enter="saveComment" is works

but
@click="saveComment" did not work.

I don't know what's the difference between these two.

I used saveComment in the methods: {} in the script.

---

edited

When I ran the function through @keypress.enter, the page was not refreshed

But when I ran the function through @click, the page was refreshed and the function was not executed.
So I added a prevent.submit and it works well.

Comment: Could you provide the JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that you only shared little information on your question, I would be answering based on some assumptions.

The keypress event is an event emitted when a key that emits is character is pressed (this event is already deprecated according to MDN, so you might want to consider keyup/letdown event).

However, you should note that the @keypress.enter event according to Vuejs would only be emitted when an individual clicks on the enter Key.
@click event on the other hand would be emitted when a click event is observed on such element, in this case a button.

Comment: I don't know why this problem happened, but it worked well when I put @submit.prevent="saveComment" on the form tag to prevent page refresh.